# Excel VBA Userform Combobox

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, match, userform

I am trying to populate a combobox with a list of letters but only those that do not appear in another range

The full list is held in a range named 'prbCodes' and I populate the combobox using this

```
For Each cClass In Range("prbCodes")
With Me.ddSelect
    .AddItem Format(cClass.Value, "")
  End With
Next cClass
```

The probes id letters in use are held in a named range 'prbList', how to I compare/match the two ranges so that only the letters that do not appear in the 'prbList' are shown in ddSelect

Thanks

EDIT:
The combobox is part of a userform, and the data is held on a sheet called 'Data'.

The two named column ranges, "prbList" and "prbCodes" are part of the data sheet. prbCodes contains the letters A-Z and numbers 0-9. prbList is a column in a table, 'tbl_probes' and contains the letters that have been used.

Comment: Should have a look at [Instr()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/instr-function)

Comment: Could you share the complete relevant code? It looks like you're populating two columns so there has to be more relevant code. Please share the shapes of the ranges i.e. if e.g. `prbList` is a single row or column, the more efficient `Application.Match` can be utilized instead of the `Find` method. It's a bit scary how you set the (named) range. Where is it located? On the same worksheet as the other one? In the same workbook as this code? Please [edit] your question adding the missing information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Populate Combobox Conditionally

```vb
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    
    ThisWorkbook.Activate
    
    Dim rgCodes As Range: Set rgCodes = Range("prbCodes")
    Dim rgList As Range: Set rgList = Range("prbList")
    
    Dim cell As Range, Code As String
    
    With Me.ddSelect
        .Clear
        .ColumnWidths = "50;50"
        .ColumnCount = 2
        For Each cell In rgCodes.Cells
            Code = CStr(cell.Value)
            If IsError(Application.Match(Code, rgList, 0)) Then
                .AddItem Code
                .List(.ListCount - 1, 1) = CStr(cell.Offset(0, 1).Value)
            End If
        Next cell
    End With
    
End Sub
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Many thanks for that code, I will try it now :) Edit: Works perfectly, thank you